# How do I send a dialog box to a registered Username

Tags: java, android, dialog

I would like to know if it's possible to send a dialog box to a registered username with ID from my database in my application?I've seen this in action in other apps but I can't seem to find any tutorials or videos on how to handle this.

For example in my application after I got the user name and ID from my friend list,I would go into another activity in where I would input some numbers after I do that I would click on the "Fight" button in which I would save those numbers in the database to be referenced later and then I would send a game invite dialog to the other player asking if he/she would like to play even if the player is logged off or logged on.

I already know how to make a dialog and I also know how to reference the player who is receiving the request but I don't know the method on how to send him/her the dialog.I would also like to know how to include the sender's ID in the dialog so when the receiver accepts the request my app would know who he/she is playing against.

Comment: you do not send a dialog to the other device, you send some information (*a message*) and the app that is in that device reacts to it (by showing the user a dialog, if it is what is programmed). You do not exchange anything other than messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may choose to do the data push using [Google Cloud Messaging Service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: its just 5 lines of code in the app that would 'register' the device, and that code is readily available. You just need to keep track of what user uses which registration code, because you are going to use that.

Comment: ok, thank you (I began checking your link so I deleted my previous question -just in case it had an obvious answer-)

Comment: Is this something that I could make my app handle or do I have to register every single device that would be used(anyone could sign up in my app it could be from 100-1,000,000 players).

Comment: You can make your app handle who registers, but its better to have all registered.